# Boolean Function to be applied to Dataframe with For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

I have writter the following function:

```
def extract_id(df, col):

column = df[col]
placement_extract = column.str.extract('(\d{14})', expand=True)

for placement in column:
    if placement in placement_extract == True:
        return placement_extract
    else:
        return 'False'

atlas_df['test'] = extract_id(atlas_df, 'PlacementName')
```

When I apply though, I get an error

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

What I'd like to do is to apply the function, if the extract is true for that placement (row) then give me the 14 numbers. If not, return the word False.

Can somebody help?

Best,

M

Comment: your data may be having NaN values, either replace them with 0 or some default number or keep an if condition to return False if placement is NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your Q 100% but, how about? (where of course you replace {3} with {13}

```
import re

def parse(s, pattern=r"(\d{3})"):
    if type(s) is str:
        match = re.search(pattern, s)
        if match:
            return match.group(0)
    return "False"

>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["123", "1 2", np.nan, None, 123]})

      a
0   123
1   1 2
2   NaN
3  None
4   123

>> df['a'].apply(parse)

0      123
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi wotalf this is amazing. It's an initial step to a more complicated function. Just out of curiosity, is it normal to place the pattern inside the function's variabile settings?

Comment: Well it depends on how you'll be using that parser. Without considerations of speed, if you'll only use that parser solely for 13 digit long numbers then you can actually define the pattern inside the function. But, if you want to use the same parser for, say, 10 digit long numbers or 5 letter long strings, then you may want to keep as an argument. I kept it as a kw argument mostly for clarity. You could just pass the pattern every time if you wanted.